# Proving this function is not surjective

Tags: functions

I have the following question $h(x)=4-x^2, x\in \Bbb{R}$

From my understanding it is only surjective when for all values in the Range that is in the Co domain there exist a $x$ value in the domain for it, so the co-domain and range must be the same, not surjective I assume that a value exist in the co domain that doesn't exist in the range.

This is what I tried:

$-(\sqrt{y-4})=x$

when y = 3:

$-(\sqrt{1})=x$

Since the co-domain is restricted to Real numbers and that is an imaginary number can I safely say that it is not surjective ?

Comment: h(1) = 3.  But, try to find something that maps to 2.

Comment: @DougM but is that the mathematical way to solve it , trying values ? i dont think i am doing it properly.

Comment: You only need one example to show that it is not a subjection.  If x is in the integers, there is no x that maps to 2, and you are done.  That is the "mathematical" way to solve it.

Comment: @user2861799 May I know the co-domain is $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$h(x) \le 4$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Therefore, there is no $x$ such that $h(x)=5$ for instance. Thus, $h$ is not surjective.

Comment: just saw an error , its Real numbers, sorry i had Integers

Comment: Just for clarity , if we had placed a boundary of some sort on the domain , we could make it surjective correct ? @lhf

Comment: @user2861799, on the domain, no; but on the codomain, yes.

Comment: yea sorry meant codomain thanks